# Problema con return route laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo la siguiente ruta:

```
Route::get('FinDraT/efectivoxpuesto/{id}/index','EfectivoxPuestoController@index');
```

y en la función del controlador hago:

```
 return redirect()->route('FinDraT/efectivoxpuesto/'. $id.'/index');
```

Y me tira el error que la ruta no esta definida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás intentando redireccionar a una URL por medio de un método que utiliza los nombres de dichas rutas.

En tu caso sería:

```
 return redirect('FinDraT/efectivoxpuesto/'. $id.'/index');
```

---

Si deseas usar el método `route()`, tendrás que asignarle un nombre a tu ruta (lo cual recomiendo):

```
Route::get('FinDraT/efectivoxpuesto/{id}/index','EfectivoxPuestoController@index')->name('miruta1');
```

en el controlador:

```
return redirect()->route('miruta1', ['id' => $id]);
```

Más información en la documentación de Laravel:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/redirects#redirecting-named-routes

Comment: Porque recomendas asignarle un nombre a la ruta?

Comment: De esa forma tu url es independiente de la ruta en cualquier parte de tu aplicación. Ejemplo: hoy tu url es **/FinDraT/blabla**, mañana cambia el algoritmo de Google y es una mejor idea que tu ruta sea **/Nuevaruta**, si le asignas un nombre, solo la cambias en tu archivo de rutas y ya. De lo contrario tendrías que cambiar las url en TODOS los lugares donde estén: controladores, servicios, middlewares, etc.